# Proving that for any vertex in a spanning tree the number of appearances of this vertex in Prüfer code is degree of this vertex minus one

Tags: sequences-and-series, graph-theory, trees

This question is not unique and has been asked before ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317475/proving-that-the-number-of-appearances-of-i-in-ft-prufer-sequence-is-d?rq=1)). My question is here since:

1. It is not about induction (or not only about induction)
2. Answer in previous question, very unfortunately, wasn't informative for me. In general, it is a good hint, but I don't know how to use it, because I can't imagine proof.

> You don't need induction; just analyze the algorithm that generates the Prüfer sequence. Whether vertex $i$ is removed during the algorithm or is one of the two vertices left over at the end of the algorithm, in either case $d_i − 1$ of its neigbours have been removed at that point, each resulting in an appearance of $i$ in the Prüfer sequence, and no further appearances of $i$ in the sequence will be generated afterwards.

So we have labeled graph $T$, vertices $v_i$, $i \in$ {$1, \cdots, n$}, $d_i$ -- degree of $v_i$
For me it is obvious that $v_i$ appears strictly $d_i - 1$ times in Prüfer code, because algorithm for building Prüfer code implies it. Vice versa, if we take any number of the Prüfer sequence and change it ($m + 1$ included), we will get another -- not origin -- graph.

But combinatorial proofs are somewhat "specific" as far as I know -- double counting proof and bijective proof.  Can we somehow use it here? If yes, how so?

Comment: Indeed, the number of occurrences of vertex $v$ in the Prüfer code is $\deg(v)$ and this follows from consideration of the code construction algorithm.  

Or you are interested in the inverse problem, that for any sequence of length $n-2$ of numbers from interval $[1,n]$ there exists a tree with such a Prüfer code.

Comment: The answer to that question is not a "good hint"; it *is* the proof. What aren't you satisfied with?

Comment: @MishaLavrov oh, if it is the proof, thеn I like combinatorics. Seems like I overcomplicated things. Thank you!